# Equirectangular lens in panoramic camera poblem

Tags: camera

I am new in Blender, and still learning. I have one problem: I watched a tutorial on 360 degree panoramic rendering and there on the camera options, on lenses I can choose Equirectangular lens. But I don't have a such a option on my Blender at my PC . How can I generate 360 degree panoramic renders? How to do this another way?

Comment: What Blender version are you using? The Equirectangular (not Ectangular!) option appears to be the top option on the Panorama Type dropdown for the Panoramic lens type in every version back to Blender 2.9.3.

Comment: It seems you should either watch the tutorial more carefully or since I don't know which one it is, it's not a well explained tutorial.

Answer (score 4):

That option is only available if you have your render engine set to Cycles

[image]

View when set to Cycles:
[image]

View when set to Eevee:
[image]